# Windows 8 - XAML - Putting Grid Inside ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Inside my XAML/C# app for Windows 8 Store, I am trying to create a ListView where each ListItem is a horizontal Grid, so I am using the XAML below:

```
  <ListView Name="ResultsView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding BestRank}" Grid.Column="0"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding BestScore}" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

When I run this program, the listview contains all the items from the list it is bound to (through code behind).  However in every list-item, contents of all three columns appear together without any space between them.  When I create a similar grid outside the listview, it displays fine and takes up entire width of the screen and divides it between the three columns as specified in the XAML above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the issue is the `ItemContainerStyle` needs to have a `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `Stretch`. Try this adding this to the ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the ListBox and the Grid should have HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"

Specify the width of the grid or add the style as a resource to the grid. Add this right after your `</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` line.

```
 <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
 </Grid.Resources>
```

This will set the properties to all of the TextBlocks in the Grid. You might only need the Margin property.  Also consider the properties Width and Padding.  You can override this default by setting the property on any given TextBlock to something that isn't the default from the Style.

Comment: But that still doesn't respect the widths I have specified in the columndefinitions.  I want my grid to span the entire width of the screen

Comment: That should work fine - you don't need to change any styles assuming your DataTemplate is ok (which it is). I've pasted your XAML into VS2010 and then set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and it works fine for me

Comment: I am trying this with Windows 8 Store apps.  Are you trying it for WPF?  VS2010 doesn't support Windows 8 Store apps.

Comment: @SometimesADeveloper no I am doing Silverlight, this kind of stuff 'should be' the same.

Comment: looks like it isn't the same

Answer (score 0):

The default ItemsPanelTemplate is a stack panel as far as I recall meaning that it won't automatically give it's children stretch behavior. You will need to change it, I will edit in a sec just on my mobile waiting for my laptop to boot up :)

Edit:

Er no ignore that I was thinking of `ItemsControl`, JBrooks is right, just make sure `HorizontalContentAlignment` is set to `Stretch` as the default is `Left`.

```
<ListView Name="ResultsView" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

That should work fine - any controls that use `XXXXContentAlignment` seem to default to `Left` which I think its a bit inconsistent vs other controls (such as `Grid`)

Answer (score 0):

actually this is not a problem of Listview. Problem is where you are putting it in? Put your list view in grid. It should work

```
<ListView Name="ResultsView" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Yellow">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BestRank}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BestScore}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: it's already inside a grid.  it's one of the rows in a multi-row grid

Comment: can you make sure that your list view is occupying the full space? may be by giving some background color you can check it..

Comment: yes I verified that.  The list view is indeed occupying the entire space

Comment: are you sure this is for Windows 8 Store apps?  I am getting this error: XamlCompiler error WMC0011: Unknown member 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'

Comment: I guess then for windows 8 store apps the listview must use a non-stretching host for it's content...I thought it was consistent across SL/WPF/Win8

Comment: HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" works for me. can you please try this? answer updated.